# How can i call a class from a Floating Button onpressed

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to use a floating action button in order to execute a class but I've been trying everything and failing. Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Dices'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {}),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int leftDiceNum = 1;
  int rightDiceNum = 1;

  void diceRandomizer() {
    setState(() {
      leftDiceNum = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      rightDiceNum = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                diceRandomizer();
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNum.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                diceRandomizer();
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightDiceNum.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now the code is a simple dice app where if i press on the images the function DiceRandomizer activates and it randomly gives a number from 1..6. then the image gets presented. But i wanna do just that with the floating action button.

Comment: When you add a tag, it is not necessary to also repeat that information in the title or post body. Doing so is just redundant noise. The tag is sufficient - the tagging system here works extremely well and doesn't need help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's because the class is undefined, and try fix your code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: DicePage()),
  );
}

class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int leftDiceNum = 1;
  int rightDiceNum = 1;

  diceRandomizer() {
    setState(() {
      leftDiceNum = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
      rightDiceNum = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Dices'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  diceRandomizer();
                },
                child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNum.png'),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  diceRandomizer();
                },
                child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightDiceNum.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {diceRandomizer();},
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){diceRandomizer();},
            
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**

- I make 2 FloatingActionButton
- FlatButton isdeprecated and must migrate to TextButton

Try that and see the result, if error you can comment and i will help you.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, it's been a heptic weekend. I haven't been able to make it work, maybe I need to study a bit more ( flutter newbie here ) but thanks a lot !

Comment: What the problem? I also newbie but i want to help you

Comment: Sorry for taking so long and thanks for for reply really appreciate it. So what i wanted to do is make the float button be able to work like the flat buttons i programmed. But im truly out of ideas. Tried different ways to call or move the code but it just wont work.